# Material UI - Button doesn't work over another component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The button has the following style:

```
floatButton: {
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    right: theme.spacing.unit * 2
}
```

And the button component looks like:

```
<Button
  className={classes.floatButton}
  variant="fab"
  color="secondary"
  onClick={this.handleHideElement}
>
  <AddIcon />
</Button>
```

The problem happens when the browser windows is small and a I can't click the button:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhxvU.png)

For some reason the button is a little transparent and the onClick function doesn't work.

How can i resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: Yeah, this is the exactly component https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/GradeProject/blob/master/client/src/components/Home/index.jsx from the line 126 to down happens the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the button a higher z-index than everything else. That should make it clickable and get rid of the transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an example of what Dylan said:

```
  <Button
    style={{zIndex: 100}}
    variant="contained">Button text
  </Button>
```